# Creating descending list of numbers from 10**6 to 10**-5 in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So I got a screen of 600 pixels. From 0 to 300 descending list must contain numbers from 10**6 to 1. I did it this way:

```
number = 10**6
numlist = [number]
for i in range(1, 299):
    number -= 10**6/299
    numlist.insert(i, number)
number = 1
numlist.insert(300,number)
```

For the next 300 pixels it should descent from 1 to 10**-5.
Can't figure out the right way of making this list

Comment: What do pixels have to do with lists?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: It's y-axis that goes from 10^6 to 10^-5. I need to output y-coordinate of the object on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will need floats anyway, you could use [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). You only need to specify the first element, the last one and how many elements there should be in the array:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.linspace(10**6, 1, num=300))
print(np.linspace(1, 10**-5, num=300))
```

And since you're working with exponents, you might want an exponential distribution:

```
print(10**np.linspace(6, -5, num=601))
```

It outputs:

```
[  1.00000000e+06   9.58664547e+05   9.19037713e+05   8.81048873e+05
   8.44630319e+05   8.09717142e+05   7.76247117e+05   7.44160590e+05
   7.13400375e+05   6.83911647e+05   6.55641849e+05   6.28540596e+05
   ...
   1.40173742e-05   1.34379597e-05   1.28824955e-05   1.23499917e-05
   1.18394992e-05   1.13501082e-05   1.08809463e-05   1.04311774e-05
   1.00000000e-05]
```